# Combining two special jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here this jQuery code:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
$(".img-one").height($(".img-two").eq(0).width());
$(".img-one").css("width", "auto");
});

$(window).resize(function(){
$(".img-one").height($(".img-two").eq(0).width());
$(".img-one").css("width", "auto");
}).trigger("resize");
```

How is it possible to combine this `.on` and `.resize`, inclusive `.trigger`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
function myFunc(){  
  $(".img-one").height($(".img-two").eq(0).width());
  $(".img-one").css("width", "auto");
}

$(window).on("load resize", myFunc).resize();
```

Comment: Thaaaaaank you!